# sql set type match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `articles` with a column being of type `SET` named `categories`.
Let's presume it accepts values from `cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4` set. Here's a visual representation:

```
articleTitle | categories (of type SET) | ID
--------------------------------------------
Socializing  | cat1                     | 1
Programming  | cat1,cat2                | 2
Sports       | cat1,cat2,cat3           | 3
Hiking       | cat2                     | 4
Nutrition    | cat1                     | 5
Health       | cat1,cat2,cat4           | 6
```

**1.** I want to do an SQL `select` to return the article name of the first **n** rows where the `val1` parameter matches any of the values from the `categories` column. **eg:** `if val1=cat1` then the results would be `Socializing, Programming, Sports, Nutrition, Health`;

**2.** I also want to do an SQL `select` query to determine if both `val1, val2` match two values from the `categories` column. **eg:** `if val1=cat1 AND val2=cat2` then the results would be `Programming, Sports, Health`;

**3.** Lastly, it would be ideal to do a query that returns the first **n** rows of articles with the highest number of matches in the `categories` column - **meaning total matches supersedes partial matches and first match from list of values takes priority over second one**. **eg:** `if val1=cat1 AND val2=cat2 AND val3=cat3 AND numerOfRows=4` then the results would be `Sports, Programming, Health, Socializing`;

How would i go about doing this? Is it even possible or do i need to run multiple queries - i guess int he multiple queries scenario the counting and matching logic would be left to the back-end side of things and i'd do one thing at a time ? Would love to get help first two scenarios still.

If there's requirement for clarification, ask and i'll amend the question.

Comment: I wish they'd never thought of SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited after rereading the question, it's correct now. SQL fiddle below:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65c5b/7

Question 1:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE categories like '%a%' LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Question 2:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE categories like '%a,b%';
```

Question 3:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE categories LIKE '%a%' or 
categories LIKE '%b%' or
categories LIKE '%c%' or
categories LIKE '%d%'
order by FIND_IN_SET('a',categories )
 + FIND_IN_SET('b',categories ) 
 + FIND_IN_SET('c',categories )
 + FIND_IN_SET('d',categories ) desc
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

I omitted the acutal CONCAT function from the variables because I don't know if this is in php, sql, or some other app, but I think it's definitely enough to get the jist of it.  Let me know if it's not.

Comment: This will be PHP. I kind of understood the logic, however i don't understand what you meant by the CONCAT function (new to SQL - really only know the basics). I'm also confused by what '%a%' means. Could you please explain? I'd like to understand it thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, and no problem! In my example, i replaced "cat1, cat2" etc with "a,b" so I hope that didn't confuse you too much.  My mistake.  The '%a%' means "Does my set contain "a"? If so return that row".

Concat is the operator to concatenate a string.  If you're using PHP, don't worry about it, since you are creating your sql in a string.  So you can do exactly what I had here which is have "cat1" or "cat2" inserted in place of my "a" "b" "c" or "d".  Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, i understood now. Thank you!